# How I can do hot cache in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have question. NodeJS need cached data for 10-30 seconds. I think redis not better solution for hot cache. Anyone know better solution?

Comment: A Map? Thats like redis but right in js.

Comment: @Jonasw map, but redis I think not good for hightload and hot cache

Comment: how many different values are you talking about? a shared global just outside an http callback is dead-simple for one cpu core's worth of  traffic. if you need to scale, redis or a custom child-process is perfect.

Comment: @dandavis 5k per sec

Comment: how many different total values at a given moment? if <2GB total, vars are fine...

Comment: @dandavis total < 100 mb

Comment: just use a variable then. an Object or a Map.  the main issue would be server crashes, but since this is just a cache anyway, that's not important.